# Extracting data from a particular column number in csv file

Tags: shell, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
arruba,jamaica, bermuda, bahama, keylargo, montigo, kokomo
80,70,90,85,86,89,83
77,75,88,87,83,85,77
76,77,83,86,84,86,84
```

I want to have a shell script set up so that I can extract out the data so that I can categorize data by columns.

I know that the line of code:

```
IFS="," read -ra arr <"vis.degrib"
for ((i=0 ; i<${#arr[@]} ; i++));do
     ifname=`printf "%s\n" "${arr[i]}"`
     echo "$ifname"
done
```

will print out the individual column components for the first row.  How do I also do this again for subsequent rows?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I don't think your script works as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm extrapolating from the OP

```
 awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^ +/,"",$i);print $i}}' vis.degrib
```

will print

```
arruba
jamaica
bermuda
bahama
keylargo
montigo
kokomo
```

note that there is trimming of the space from the beginning of each field.  If you remove the condition `NR==1`, the same will be done for all rows.  Was this your request?  Please comment...

Perhaps you want to convert columnar format to row based format (transpose)?  There are many ways, this awk script will do

```
 awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sep=(NR==1)?"":OFS} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=a[i] sep $i} END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i]}' vis.degrib
```

will print

```
arruba,80,77,76
jamaica,70,75,77
 bermuda,90,88,83
 bahama,85,87,86
 keylargo,86,83,84
 montigo,89,85,86
 kokomo,83,77,84
```

you can again trim the space from the beginning of the labels as shown above.

Another approach without awk.

```
 tr ',' '\n' <vis.degrib | pr -4ts,
```

will generate the same

```
 arruba,80,77,76
 jamaica,70,75,77
  bermuda,90,88,83
  bahama,85,87,86
  keylargo,86,83,84
  montigo,89,85,86
  kokomo,83,77,84
```

`4` is the number of rows in the original file.